# ROS Answers SE migration: robot rviz tf

Tags: joint, rviz, state, robot, publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am new to ROS. I tryed to use the Pioneer 3-AT urdf model provided in the p2os-Master stack.If I have a frame tree for this robot, and want to show this robot in a fixed map, in Rviz, I would only have to broadcast its transform with parent link: static_map, for example, and child link: base_link and publish the joint states for the joints that are not fixed, if I have robot_state_publisher running. Is that correct?

I checked in the tf topic. All transforms are being published as expected, but in Rviz, when I put the static_map as fixed frame, it says there are only transforms for the base_link and the static_map. Do I need to broadcast all the transforms with the static_map as the parent link? I did one publisher priorly which I only broadcasted the transform for the static_map and published the joints that were not fixed, and that worked.

I had divided the nodes to be launched in 2 diferent launch files, when I tryed to launch then all in one launch file, in Rviz, it says there are tansforms for all, but only the transform for base_link is correct, all others stay on ground beneath the base_link frame.

What should I do?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/113186/robot-rviz-tf/) by [Ohashi](https://answers.ros.org/users/5336/ohashi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 58 on 2013-12-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just added the value for w in the transform.rotation with static_map as parent and it worked, I don't know why tough.

---

Originally posted by [Ohashi](https://answers.ros.org/users/5336/ohashi/) with karma: 58 on 2013-12-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-12-27**:
You cannot do transform math with invalid quaternions. The transforms will get dropped instead of being integrated and giving bad results.